# Neo4j spatial - Find points before and after a specific point in a way

Tags: neo4j, openstreetmap, neo4j-spatial

I am loading my OSM data to graph database. I created a layer (simple point layer) on top of it to load all the points from the graph db. After adding all the points to the layer, I am able to find closest points in a certain kilometer distance. 
But I am not able to figure out an option which will give me the points before and after a specific point in a way. Can you please give me some clue to solve this problem?

Comment: BTW: everything that include nearest neighbour or routing could be solved also with the open source routing engine GraphHopper (note: I'm one of authors)

Answer (score 0):

If you used the OSM importer that is available with Neo4j Spatial there will be a `:NEXT` relationship connecting the nodes in a way. So you can traverse the nodes (points) by following the `:NEXT` relationships. For example:

```
// find node within 1m of a point
CALL spatial.withinDistance('geom',
{latitude: 37.563440, longitude: -122.322265}, 1) YIELD node AS p
// traverse graph to find next point in the way
MATCH (p)-[:NEXT]->(nextPoint)
RETURN nextPoint
```